# Text search elements in a big python list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

With a list that looks something like:

```
cell_lines = ["LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM","769P_KIDNEY","786O_KIDNEY"]
```

With my dabbling in regular expressions, I can't figure out a compelling way to search individual strings in a list besides looping through each element and performing the search.

How can I retrieve indices containing "KIDNEY" in an efficient way (since I have a list of length thousands)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[line for line in cell_lines if "KIDNEY" in line]
```

This is `O(n)` since we check every item in a list to contain `KIDNEY`.

If you would need to make similar queries like this often, you should probably think about reorganizing your data and have a dictionary grouped by categories like `KIDNEY`:

```
{
    "KIDNEY": ["769P_KIDNEY","786O_KIDNEY"],
    "NERVOUS_SYSTEM": ["LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM"]
}
```

In this case, every "by category" lookup would take "constant" time.

Comment: A list comprehension works perfectly. I was really over thinking this one with regexes...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` instead of a `list` since it performs lookups in constant time.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def bi_contains(lst, item):
    """ efficient `item in lst` for sorted lists """
    # if item is larger than the last its not in the list, but the bisect would 
    # find `len(lst)` as the index to insert, so check that first. Else, if the 
    # item is in the list then it has to be at index bisect_left(lst, item)
    return (item <= lst[-1]) and (lst[bisect_left(lst, item)] == item)
```

Slightly modifying the above code will give you pretty good efficiency.

Here's a list of the data structures available in Python along with the time complexities.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Thanks, I considered a set, but I need my cell lines ordered.